# Shopware 6 and counting of VAT

Tags: shopware, tax

Can anyone explain how Shopware counts VAT in total price for Cart?

I have a cart with one product that costs 1.309 euro. Tax rate is 19%, so tax value is 0.24871. This I can understand: 1.309/100*19=0,24871.

But then it adds shipping cost (2 euro). It somehow makes 3.3074732824427 euro (don't konow how), but even more strange for me that 19% from this amount makes 0.56871. How they are calculating this? 3.307/100*19 is about 0.63, and 3.307/119*19 is about 0.53, but not 0.57.

Also, is there any way to change this algorithm programmatically? I use in my Calculator $this->taxCalculator->calculateNetTaxes() for every product, but it doesn't count total sum. And method $toCalculate->setPrice() in my CartProcessor doesn't work.

Comment: It depends on your settings, you can define for each sales channel, which method to calculate the taxes you want to use. And it also depends on the settings of your shipping costs.

Comment: Why do you have so strange prices? You should avoid more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If 1.309 is a gross price, it means that tax is included and in fact it is 119% (net prices(100%) + VAT(19%)).
So VAT of product is (1.309/119)*19 = 0.209

VAT of shipping is (2/119)*19 = 0.319.... (by same logic)

and at the end 0.209+0.319 = 0.528

Comment: I know this. But why Shopware says 0.56871? And is there any way to correct its algorthm?

Comment: I think you need to check `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Tax\TaxCalculator` and debug it. Especially `calculateTaxFromNetPrice` and `calculateTaxFromGrossPrice` methods. Check tax rules which are applied to your cart and make sure that settings are correct.